# SQL Server database to Excel pivot table

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a SQL Server database with two tables (there are more, but this is for purpose of the question).

Table **Projects**:

```
ProdID int
ProjectName String
```

Table **Tasks**:

```
TaskId int
TaskName String
ProdID FK to Projects.ProdID
```

I would like to make a pivot table in excel using those two tables.

I was able to make a connecting using "connect datasource -> SQL Server database -> use tables/import relations" and that works correctly.

However, I cannot find the way to remove FKs from the pivot table view. Basically user can see and use ProdID TK from Tasks table in Pivot and that screws whole thing up.

I tried using views, that however removes the relationships and FKs don't work.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: You can create pivot via SQL Server and than import it in Excel.

Comment: How about using and excel query instead of the import wizard?

Comment: With excel query i can only import one table and in this case i need multiple tables with relations between them.

Comment: already heard of [Power Pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Pivot)? You can reproduce your SQL data model in Excel with this Microsoft add-in... and you can do much more as with a conventional pivot-table.